# Exception in DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, exception, datepicker

i am trying to create a DatePickerDialog in the class 'dateDisplay.class'. I am calling this activity from 'main.class'. If I call the 'dateDisplay.class' using startActivity(), then the DatePickerDialog works fine. But actually I am using an ActivityGroup (for using tab in my application) and I am starting the 'dateDisplay.class'  using the following code :

```
    Intent dateIntent=new Intent(context,dateDisplay.class);
    View v=getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("2",dateIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
    setContentView(v);
```

But an exception is caught, on calling the  onCreateDialog() function. And  the process is suddently stopped. It shows TargetInvocationException is occured. How can I correct the code?
Following is my code:

```
public  Dialog onCreateDialog(int id,Bundle b)
     {
       Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
       int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
       int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
       int year=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
       Dialog d = null;
       if(id==DATE_DIALOG_ID)
       {
          return    new DatePickerDialog(this,dateChangeListener,year,month,day); 
       }

       else
       {
               return null;
         }


     }
```

Please help me..
Thank you..

Comment: could you post the complete log of the exception?

Comment: Is the 'id' equal to your DATE_DIALOG_ID when calling the function?

Comment: id and DATE_DIALOG_ID are equal to 1

Answer (score 1):

just use this code to solve the problem

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            switch (id) {
            case 0:

            return new DatePickerDialog(this,  mDateSetListener,  cyear, cmonth, cday);
            }
            return null;
            }

            private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String date_selected = String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" /"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" /"+String.valueOf(year);

            EditText birthday=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextBirthday);
            birthday.setText(date_selected);
            }
            };
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(v == ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pickDate)))
            showDialog(0);

            }

        }
```